# How to pass values to an instance that is made without any constructor being called

Tags: c#, struct, constructor, instance

I know there is a difference between creating an instance that uses the constructor with no para vs creating an instance that doesnt use a constructor. I called my instance like this:

```
Animal cat; //Animal is a struc
```

Now if I try passing in two values like this I get an error:

```
//cat(1,2);
```

I dont have this issue if I create the instance that uses a constructor. What should I do?

Comment: What is definition of `Animal` struct?

Comment: "creating an instance that doesnt use a constructor" There is no such concept.

Comment: That looks like c++ style initialization, not c#

Comment: `cat(1,2)` would be method calling syntax and not instantiating a struct

Comment: "I dont have this issue if I create the instance that uses a constructor. What should I do?"  -- You should create the instance using the constructor...

Comment: You could name properties within cat, initialize it somewhere else and do something like 'cat.whiskers' but what you're attempting to do is not possible as you need to initialize the instance to pas it values as such.

Comment: "I get an error " Please provide the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Animal is a struct as you said, you can only pass in value when you define your variables like

```
Animal cat=new Animal(1,2)
```

if you have defined it without passing in values, you can only do it like

```
cat.x=1
cat.y=2
```

Comment: is x a private/protected member?

Comment: @ManojKumarRai no they are public

Comment: @Brogrammer it should work if x is a public member, what is the error message

Comment: @user3851167 Never mind it does work apparently I was trying to do cat.property instead of the member variable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your intention was [object initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) or object initialization expressions:

```
public void Foo()
{
    Animal cat = new Animal() { AnimalType = "cat", Sound = "myauuuuuu" };
}


struct Animal
{
    public string AnimalType;
    public string Sound;
}
```

There are incidents that object initializers provide a very convenient and readable way to create an object.